# Confused about NP hard and reduction

Tags: algorithm, np-hard

By definition NP-hard is **at least as hard as the hardest problems in NP**.

And [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) states

> a problem H is NP-hard when every problem L in NP can be reduced in
>   polynomial time to H

So if the time complexity of H is O(H), the every L can be solved in O(n^k)*O(H). Then H is the faster then every L? Why H is harder then every L?

Comment: At the bottom of each SO page is a list of sister sites. Not so hard to find [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) there.

Comment: "X is harder than Y" in this context means that if X is solvable in polynomial time, then so is Y. Trying to put a more engineering interpretation on it using ideas of speed and big-O isn't a good idea -- the words "hard" and "hardest" are being used in a specific sense to informally explain the more precise technical language.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : ​ ​ ​ However, this question would be immediately closed on that site, since this question is way too low-level. ​ The right site would be [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yeah, I should have looked a little lower.